# Function minimization as genetic algorithm stop condition

Tags: genetic-algorithms

I have implemented genetic algorithm for a problem where I have an objective function which I need to minimize:

```
Cost = ax + by + cz -> min
```

The genetic algorithm should have found the optimal solution if objective function is satisfied.

The function will never reach 0 or below, so I just need to minimize it. Now, since there are no objective values to be reached, how do I know whether the objective function is satisfied or not?

Comment: You dont. Just try a bunch of values (try smaller ones first, then increase them slowly) for how much time to train it, and find what is good enough for you

Comment: So the real stop condition should be reaching the number of maximum iterations?

Comment: Yes, and that number you define (so it wont take years but still will be approximately good when its done)

Comment: Okay, and how do I "find" that number? By trial and error?

Comment: This is a generic thing done in most learning algorithms to my knowledge

Comment: Yes, by trial and error

Comment: Oh, and if it wasnt clear, then that "time" variable is the number of learning iterations done, not the amount of "real time" passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three typical stopping criteria:

1. You have reached a sufficient value
2. Your *new optimal value* hasn't changed for the past $n$ minutes/generations
3. Your time (and patience) runs out.

The best case scenario is Case 1.  These are the cases where you are looking for a *good enough* solution, and you have found a solution that is good enough.  This criterion depends on you actually being able to set such a value, of course.

Typically Case 2 is better than Case 3 when it works out.  Here you don't abort your simulation as long as "it's improving" and therefore hasn't found the optimal solution.

But some times you get to borrow the cluster for 2 weeks, and then that's when you shut it off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and how would you choose `n` for #2?